# Categorize the File Hierarchy System

Tags: filesystem

I found the file system hard to remember, since they are not categorized properly.

I tried to categorize them as the follows

[image]

Could you please offer any comment to revise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend trying to categorize the root directory hierarchy, since some directories could belong to multiple categories. `/proc` for instance isn't only relevant to `boot` and `run` categories as in the table in your question. A good example of that are `/proc/cpuinfo` and `/proc/devices`  - these provide information about hardware rather than anything specific to (just) booting and running executables.

The [Filesystem Hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) is a Standard maintained by Linux foundation, and since Ubuntu is based on Debian, there's also a page in [Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) that addresses these. If we are going to categorize things, let's consider the mentioned Debian page, with the highlighted parts. Roughly you could summarize them into:

- Binaries(aka executable files, though they may contain other data): `/bin/`, `/usr/bin`, `/opt`
- Devices and filesystems: `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/media/`, `/mnt`. Yes, `/proc`, `/dev/` and `/sys` are virtual filesystems exposed by kernel.
- Data and configurations: `/etc/`, `/var`, `/tmp`, `/usr`. Note that `/usr` is here because as stated in Debian page this is "[s]econdary hierarchy for shareable, read-only data" and "files that are not-required to boot or rescue the system"
- User directories: `/home`
- Libraries for binaries: `/lib`

Keep in mind, this category isn't official, but these are the categories that would use Linux/Unix terminology. Note also that this is also not exhaustive set of categories, but they're broad enough to address possible uses for each directory, as in `/proc` example.